# How can I execute multiple lein tasks in one command?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm new to leiningen.

When I tried to execute following,

```
$ lein clean jar
```

I got

```
Wrong number of arguments to clean task. 
Expected []
$
```

How can I execute multiple tasks in one command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to execute multiple *leiningen* tasks in sequence with one command.

Example:

```
lein do clean, test
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it at the command line directly, but you can with an alias in your `project.clj` file:

```
:aliases
{"go" ["do" "clean," "jar"]}
```

So at the command line you would then be able to:

```
lein go
```

(The comma after `clean` is needed, because `lein do` expects a comma after each command in order to allow passing arguments to the commands.)

Comment: `:aliases
{"go" ["do" "clean," "jar"]}` I had to add the comma for a project where I needed to wait on the build. Just a heads up