# In Leiningen invoke another task from test task

Tags: leiningen

For running tests I use the default test task in Leiningen like

`lein test`

As part of this task I wanted to run another plugin task. Specifically the lein-cljfmt plugins check command which can be invoked in a standalone manner like

`lein cljfmt check`

Is it possible to run the `cljfmt check` command as part of the lein test task invocation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute multiple lein tasks in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914444/how-can-i-execute-multiple-lein-tasks-in-one-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can define an alias under the `aliases` key. Thus if your test alias is the only alias in your project.clj file, `aliases` would look like this:

```
:aliases {"test" ["do" "test" ["cljfmt" "check"]]}
```

With this alias set up `lein test` would now actually be doing `lein do test, cljfmt check`.

See https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj for examples.